# QT: Detecting left and right mouse press events on QGraphicsItem

Tags: c++, qt, events, graphics, qt5

I am having trouble registering right click on my custom QGraphics item.

My custom class's header:

```
#ifndef TILE_SQUARE_H
#define TILE_SQUARE_H
#include <QPainter>
#include <QGraphicsItem>
#include <QtDebug>
#include <QMouseEvent>

class Tile_Square : public QGraphicsItem
{
public:
Tile_Square();

bool Pressed;
int MovementCostValue;

QRectF boundingRect() const;
void paint(QPainter *painter,const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option, QWidget *widget);


protected:
    void mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event);
    void contextMenuEvent(QGraphicsSceneContextMenuEvent *cevent);


};
#endif // TILE_SQUARE_H
```

And here is the implementation of said class:

```
    #include "tile_square.h"

Tile_Square::Tile_Square()
{
    Pressed = false;
    MovementCostValue = 1;

}

QRectF Tile_Square::boundingRect() const
{
    return QRectF(0,0,10,10);
}

void Tile_Square::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option, QWidget *widget)
{
    QRectF rec = boundingRect();
    QBrush brush(Qt::white);

    painter->fillRect(rec,brush);
    painter->drawRect(rec);
}

//Left click
void Tile_Square::mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event)
{
    QMouseEvent *mouseevent = static_cast<QMouseEvent *>(*event);
    if(mouseevent->buttons() == Qt::LeftButton){
        MovementCostValue++;
        qDebug() << "LEFT: Movement value is: " << MovementCostValue;
    }
    else if(mouseevent->buttons() == Qt::RightButton){
        MovementCostValue--;
        qDebug() << "RIGHT: Movement value is: " << MovementCostValue;
    }
    update();
    QGraphicsItem::mousePressEvent(event);


}
```

I am drawing this on a Dialog window with a graphicsview and a graphicsscene.

I wanto increase the internal int of the class on left click, and decrease it on right click. Problem is, mousepressevent registers the event and not which button was pressed. In my code you can see i tried to cast it to regular Mouse Event, but failed, obviously.

Honestly i want to write

```
event->buttons() == Qt::LeftButton
```

but the QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event does not have such one. What is the issue?

I also tried using the contextmenuevent, which works perfectly and registers the right click, but the regular mousepressevent gets registered too.

Comment: Why are you not just using [QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent::button](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsscenemouseevent.html#button)?

Comment: You mean implement it inside the mousepressevent?

Comment: No, I mean [QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsscenemouseevent.html) *has* the functionality you require with regard to finding which button was pressed etc.  Check the docs in the link.  Or am I misunderstanding your question?

Comment: I did check it, but i don't understand it. How would i use it?

I can't call   event->buttons() in the if loop to check it, like i would do normally.

Comment: What happens if you just replace `mouseevent->buttons()` with `event->button()` in your code?

Comment: Nothing, event-> points to nothing, i can't write anything there. Which is really strange, that is why i tried workarounds, like static casting and context event.

Comment: When you say "can't write anything there", do you mean that Intellisense doesn't provide you with any options, or that you try "event->buttons()" and it doesn't compile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you cannot cast from `QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent` to `QMouseEvent`. `QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent` doesn't derive from `QMouseEvent`, so that's just not a safe cast to make. The buttons method is probably not actually calling the right method because that cast is bad. Second, `QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent::buttons` does exist, and it does what you want, but it's a mask. You should be doing this:

```
#include <QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent>

void Tile_Square::mousePressEvent (QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event)
{
    if (event->buttons() & Qt::LeftButton)
    {
        // ... handle left click here
    }
    else if (event->buttons() & Qt::RightButton)
    {
        // ... handle right click here
    }
}
```

Even without treating this as a mask, I would expect that your direct comparison is likely to work as long as you don't press a combination of buttons at once. However, I haven't tested that to be sure.

Comment: That was the first thing i tried. However event-> doesn't point to anything. I can't call button() nor buttons() nor anything that SHOULD be there.

Comment: If `event` is a null pointer (as you seem to suggest) then there is something *very* wrong elsewhere in your code.

Comment: But my code is literally this. Only the scene and view creator in the dialog are the other code.

Comment: Yeah, I'm with GM. The mousePressEvent method doesn't get called with a null pointer...ever. Also, if it were null, your cast to QMouseEvent would still result in a null pointer, so that should crash. None of this makes sense. Also, I just realized that your static_cast can't even compile; you're dereferencing the pointer and then trying to cast something that isn't a pointer, so it's wrong on multiple levels. In this code, if you replace what you have with what I provided in my answer, it should be fine. Something is wrong elsewhere.

Comment: Oh i am so stupid!! I totally forgot to #include <QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent> and did not notice in your code. Thank you!

Comment: I was wondering if that's all that was wrong... :) Always nice when it's something simple.